# Ninject 3.2 BindFilter constructor binding broken when using Ninject.Extension.Factory 3.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, factory

I have an MVC5, WebApi application that works fine if I don't include the Ninject.Extension.Factory 3.2.0.0 3/21/2014 build. Once I add that package the application has the following exception:

```
Error activating EntitleActionFilter using self-binding of EntitleActionFilter
Several constructors have the same priority. Please specify the constructor using ToConstructor syntax or add an Inject attribute.

Constructors:
EntitleActionFilter(List{NavigationItem} navigationItemsFunc{IEnumerable{string}} permissionFunc)
EntitleActionFilter(List{NavigationItem} navigationItemsFunc{IEnumerable{int}} permissionFuncInt)
```

I'm using the following Ninject packages (all Friday, 3/21/2014 builds):

- Ninject 3.2.0.0
- Ninject.MVC5 3.2.0.0
- Ninject.Web.Common 3.2.0.0
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.2.0.0

Those two constructors are unique. The bindings look like:

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>> permissionFunc = () => Kernel.Get<INavigationPermissionsProvider>().GetPermissionsInt();

this.BindFilter<EntitleActionFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
    .WithConstructorArgument("navigationItems",
         context => context.Get<NavigationHelper>().GetNavigation().NavigationItems)
    .WithConstructorArgument("permissionFuncInt", permissionFunc);
```

I do use Ninject factories a lot and need this package. If I remove the Ninject.Extensions.Factory 3.2 package, everything works. This same code worked with the previous 3.0 version of Ninject and the factory extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to the factory extension. The factory extension just adds bindings for all Func overloads which means both constructors can be satisfied completely.

With Ninject 3.0 any of the constructor is chosen if there were several with the same priority. There is no guarantee that always the same one is picked. Which one is picked is decided by the implementation of some .NET Framework functions that give no guarantee about ordering. In the worst case it means that the .NET framework version decides what constructor is picked.

Ninject 3.2 throws now an exception if there are several constructors with the same priority so that you have to configure which constructor is taken, so that always the correct one is picked.

If I were you I wouldn't use an Func as dependency but instead inject an instance of `INavigationPermissionsProvider` and call `GetPermissionsInt()`

Comment: Remo, thanks for the quick response! I'm not sure why these constructors would have the same priority. They have different types, different parameter names and I am binding to the specific constructor.
  
    EntitleActionFilter(List{NavigationItem} navigationItemsFunc{IEnumerable{[bold]string/bold]}} permissionFunc)
    
    EntitleActionFilter(List{NavigationItem} navigationItemsFunc{IEnumerable{[bold]int[/bold]}} permissionFuncInt)

Comment: No you are not binding to a specific constructor. This would be done by the other overload of BindFilter. You are binding a filter and tell Ninject it can select the constructor it feels fits best and add two constructor arguments it might use. Ninject finds two constructors each with 2 parameters it knows how to satisfy. The rule is to take the constructor with the most parameters. So both are equal.